# JCL for copying certain members from one PDS to another

Tags: mainframe, jcl

I am trying to copy some members from one PDS to another. Suppose I have 500 members in one PDS. I am trying to move the first 100 to the second PDS, the next 100 to the third PDS, and so on. The members which are copied to another PDS should also be deleted from the source PDS.

Is it possible to do this using JCL? I am looking at IEBGENER but there I found we can directly copy members by specifying names.

Comment: Wow - I have heard about or done JCL  for years. I would really like to see an answer to this for nostalgia's sake

Comment: IS this a homework question? What business need is there to split the input file by each 100 members?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in several job steps. As an outline:

- Trap the output from LISTDS 'input-pds-name' MEMBERS into a dataset
- manipulate the MEMBERS list with ICETOOL to produce IDCAMS REPRO and DELETE commands
- run the IDCAMS REPRO
- run the IDCAMS DELETE

Setting up ICETOOL to select and format the MEMBERS list into REPRO/DELETE commands
is, by far, the most difficult step. In fact you might need to chain a couple
of ICETOOL steps to get all straight. This could take a very long time
to figure out unless you have a lot of experience 
using ICETOOL. Here
is a link to the [IBM DFSORT Programming Guide](http://publibfp.boulder.ibm.com/cgi-bin/bookmgr_OS390/BOOKS/ICE1CA20/CCONTENTS?)
(ICETOOL is just a BATCH front end to DFSORT) to give you some idea of what you
are up against.

I suggest an alternative approach. Try writing a REXX procedure to replace the
ICETOOL step. Trapping the LISTDS output and formatting it into the
appropriate IDCAMS REPRO/DELETE commands would be a much simpler process.

REXX is available on pretty much every IBM mainframe so access should not be a problem.

Please provide a bit more detail on your dataset naming conventions if you need
more help with this. Particularly, the output PDS names. I don't need or want
exact names, just how they are constructed. For example do they looks something
like this:

- HLQ.SOMENAME.FILE001
- HLQ.SOMENAME.FILE002
- HLQ.SOMENAME.FILE003

where the first 100 members are copied into FILE001, the next 100 to FILE002
etcetera. This can make a difference in how generalized you can make
the file copy utility. Also, do you keep copying in blocks of 100 until
the input PDS is exausted or is there some stopping limit?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a product called "SAS' then it will be very easy to copy selected members from one PDS to other.

```
DATA PDS;                                              
FILENAME OLD 'A*.B*.C*' DISP=SHR;              
FILENAME NEW 'A*.B*.D*' DISP=OLD;
PROC PDSCOPY INDD=OLD OUTDD=NEW ALIASMATCH=BOTH        
SHAREINPUT;                                      
SELECT  AJ:;                                        
RUN;
```

Note: All the members starting with AJ will copy from old to new dataset.

Comment: This may work, but this answer doesn't address the OP's homework, er, I mean, genuine business requirement.